# Safari open new tabs to the far right (end)

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

How can I make Safari open new tabs to the far right (end) and not immediately to the right of my existing tab which is the current behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you talking about new tab opened by clicking on a link or new empty tab opened by using the keyboard shortcut Command + T?

Answer (score 1):

This [Cult of Mac article](https://www.cultofmac.com/691905/how-to-force-safari-tabs-open-at-end-of-tab-bar/) worked for me. Basically, activate the Debug menu in Safari from the Terminal using:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1
```

Restart Safari. You should now see a Debug menu. Select **Debug** > **Tab Ordering** > **After Last Tab**. Additionally, check options **Apply Position to Spawned Tabs** and **Apply Position to All Blank Tabs**.